# Java Package. Cannot use more than one package per file

Tags: java, netbeans-7

I am a beginner programmer for the FRC team 1310.I use Java in the Netbeans IDE. I was trying to incorporate certain classes. There is a package for FRC that is called `edu.wpi.first.wpilibj.templates`, it allows us to use speed controllers and sensors for our robot. I want to import `java` and `javax` classes along with the `edu.wpi.first.wpilibj.templates` package on the same file. i need this for Japplets to make it interactive. I also need this for the URL function as I need to extract images from an AXIS camera.

How do I do this?

Help is really needed.

Comment: Could you show the code and your error message?

Answer (score 1):

Use `import` instead of `package`. My guess is you have multiple lines that start with the word `package` at the top of your file. To use classes from another package you `import` them.

```
package com.myPackage.whatever;

import java.io.*;
import javax.whatever.you.Want;
import edu.wpi.first.wpilibj.templates.*;
```

Comment: the wdu.wpi.wpi.first.wpilibj.templated is the package and when i put an import to it it gives an error. the error is that the package clashes with class of same name. and i cant still import javax.ehatever.whatever;

Answer (score 0):

Your question doesn't really make sense.

To import multiple packages just put multiple import statements at the top of your file...

If you mean you need to INHERIT multiple parent classes from one class then you can't do that. Java only supports single inheritance. You need to use composition (create multiple classes, each inheriting one of the things you want, then have one single class containing all those).